# Nested Playa, Matrix and reverse_related_entries

Tags: matrix, playa, relationships, reverse-related-entries

Ok, it'll be a miracle if anyone can help me here, but I have an EE-1 site (upgrading is not an option here) with the following:

```
{exp:weblog:entries ...}
   {reverse_related_entries limit="1"}
      <h2>{title}</h2> <!-- all good so far -->
      {a_matrix_field}
         <p>{a_matrix_column}</p> <!-- still good -->
         {a_playa_field} 
            {title} <!-- fail -->
         {/a_playa_field}
      {/a_matrix_field}
   {/reverse_related_entries}
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

The playa field outputs some garbage along the lines of `{REL[1355][a_matrix_field]AcYdXsrHREL}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just pass the `entry_id` to an embed.

```
{exp:weblog:entries ...}
   {reverse_related_entries limit="1"}
      {embed="some/template" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
   {/reverse_related_entries}
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

Embed:

```
{exp:weblog:entries entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" ...}
      <h2>{title}</h2> 
      {a_matrix_field}
         <p>{a_matrix_column}</p> 
         {a_playa_field} 
            {title}
         {/a_playa_field}
      {/a_matrix_field}
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks Siebird. I was just in the middle of doing something similar with an embed inside the matrix (very bad idea, resulting in a dozen embeds being generated). This way is much more sensible and the performance hit is acceptable!

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help!